# Get data from fragment and send it to activity

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, send

I have an activity in which i desire to retrieve data (the text in some edit texts) when i click  a button in my toolbar :

```
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            break;
        case R.id.mnufragmentOk:

            RETRIEVE EDITTEXT!!

            break;
}
```

this is my activity :

```
public class ViatgeDetallTransportActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_transportation);

       Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tlbMenuTransportation);
       setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
      getSupportActionBar().setTitle("TravelApp ACtFra");
       getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
       getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            ViatgeDetallTransportFragment fragment = new ViatgeDetallTransportFragment();

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.activity_fragment_transportation,fragment)  
                    .commit();
        }
    }
```

And my fragment class :

```
public class ViatgeDetallTransportFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_ID = "id";

    public ViatgeDetallTransportFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_transportation, container, false);


        return rootView;
    }
}
```

With a simple layout  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout_fragment_transportation" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Transportation"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edtTitleFragmentTransportation"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edtDescripcioFragmentTransportation"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edtTypeFragmentTransportation"/>




</LinearLayout>
```

In the activity, when I click the toolbar button "mnufragmentOk" i want to recieve the data in the edit texts, so i can create a  custom object.

Answer (score 2):

Keep the fragment instance as a global variable in Activity

```
    public class ViatgeDetallTransportActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
 ViatgeDetallTransportFragment fragment;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_transportation);

       Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tlbMenuTransportation);
       setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
      getSupportActionBar().setTitle("TravelApp ACtFra");
       getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
       getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

 fragment = new ViatgeDetallTransportFragment();

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.activity_fragment_transportation,fragment)  
                    .commit();
        }
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            break;
        case R.id.mnufragmentOk:

           String s=fragment.getFirstEditTextData();

            break;
}
    }
```

Impliment the `getFirstEditTextData()` method inside of your Fragment

Answer (score 1):

You can set a TAG for your fragment:

```
ViatgeDetallTransportFragment fragment = new ViatgeDetallTransportFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.activity_fragment_transportation,fragment, "MyFragment").commit();
```

Then you can find that instance when you click the button:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        break;
    case R.id.mnufragmentOk:

        ViatgeDetallTransportFragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("MyFragment");

        break;
}
```

Finally, you can find the TextView and get it's value:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        break;
            case R.id.mnufragmentOk:

            ViatgeDetallTransportFragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("MyFragment");
            EditText editText = (EditText)fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
            String string = editText.getText().toString().trim();

        break;
}
```

plus:
don't forget to set an ID to your EditTexts:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/my_edit_text"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/edtTypeFragmentTransportation"/>
```

and you need to reference them in your fragment's view creation:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_transportation, container, false);

    EditText editText = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_edit_text);

    return rootView;
}
```